# Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file: * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of t

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, configuration

I get this error when i try to run my script on the rinkeby network: Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

- Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a
  value of type string.

```
     require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.1',
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY,
      accounts: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
    },
   
  },
};
```

.env File

```
  
   process.env.STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY=https://eth-rinkeby.dotdotdot          
                                                                                 
   process.env.PRIVATE_KEY=PRIVATE_KEY
```

Comment: It is possible , you don't have .env file or don't have **PRIVATE_KEY = "your private key"** in your .env file

Comment: I have a .env file with my private key and Alchemy API key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from the .env file. The prefix `process.env` in front of the environment variable isn't needed. I removed it leaving just the `STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY` and `PRIVATE_KEY` variables and their values.